# Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I have a function

```
onSelectRow(key){
  // console.log(key,tableData[key]);
      this.setState({
        rowSelectKey : key,
        rowSelectValue: tableData[key]
      });
}
```

in the TableUser class. and I am using it in `<Table>` properties.

```
<Table
      height={this.state.height}
      fixedHeader={this.state.fixedHeader}
      fixedFooter={this.state.fixedFooter}
      selectable={this.state.selectable}
      multiSelectable={this.state.multiSelectable}
      onRowSelection={this.onSelectRow}
    >
```

now, when the table row is selected, I can see an error is caught in console `Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function`

But If I am using an arrow function for `onSelectRow` then flow goes well, but the table row checkbox is not working.

N.B: I tried using bind, same checkbox problem remains, but functionality goes well.

Updated:

Here is the code for the Table where I am rendering values from back end.
And I am selecting the row data of the `<Table>` to edit it or Delete it.

To select the `<Table>` row I am using the method `onSelectRow()` thats what I am using an arrow function, which prevents me selecting the row of the table.

```
export default class TableUser extends React.Component {
componentDidMount(){
this.props.dispatch(getUserList())
//this.setState({tableData:this.props.userList})
}
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
    fixedHeader: true,
    fixedFooter: true,
    stripedRows: true,
    showRowHover: false,
    selectable: true,
    multiSelectable: false,
    enableSelectAll: true,
    deselectOnClickaway: true,
    showCheckboxes: true,
    tableData: [], //initial state for tableData
    rowSelectKey : '',
    rowSelectValue: ''
}
// this.onSelectRow=this.onSelectRow.bind(this);
}
onSelectRow=(key)=>{
// console.log(this.state.key,this.state.tableData[key]);
  this.setState({
    rowSelectKey : this.state.key,
    rowSelectValue: this.props.userList[key],
  });
  // this.state.rowSelectKey=key;
  // this.state.rowSelectValue=tableData[key];
}
render() {
return (
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiThemebtn}>
  <div className="table">
   <br/>
   <Table
      height={this.state.height}
      fixedHeader={this.state.fixedHeader}
      fixedFooter={this.state.fixedFooter}
      selectable={this.state.selectable}
      multiSelectable={this.state.multiSelectable}
      onRowSelection={this.onSelectRow}
    >
      <TableHeader
        displaySelectAll={this.state.showCheckboxes}
        adjustForCheckbox={this.state.showCheckboxes}
        enableSelectAll={this.state.enableSelectAll}
      >
        <TableRow>
          <TableHeaderColumn colSpan="4" tooltip="" style={{textAlign: 'left',fontSize:'16',
            fontWeight:'700',color:'black'}}>
            <p style={{float:'left',marginTop:'7px'}}>Users</p>
            <FlatButton
              icon={<ContentAddBox />}
              style={{float: 'left'}}
            />
            <div className="manageedituserbtn">
              <DeleteModal/>
            </div>
            <div className="manageedituserbtn">
              <EditModal/>
            </div>
            <FlatButton
              icon={<SocialShare/>}
              style={{float: 'right'}}
            />
            <FlatButton
              icon={<MapsLocalOffer/>}
              style={{float:'right'}}
            />            
          </TableHeaderColumn>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
          <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="Name">Name</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="Role">Role</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="Phone">Phone</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="Email">Email</TableHeaderColumn>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHeader>
      <TableBody
        displayRowCheckbox={this.state.showCheckboxes}
        deselectOnClickaway={this.state.deselectOnClickaway}
        showRowHover={this.state.showRowHover}
        stripedRows={this.state.stripedRows}
      >
          {this.props.userList.map((row, index) => ( 
          <TableRow key={index}>
            <TableRowColumn>{row.name}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{row.role}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{row.phone}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{row.email}</TableRowColumn>
          </TableRow>
          ))}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  </div>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);
```

}
};

Now can you tell me, why I am not able to click the check box of the `<Table>` row?

Answer (score 0):

first I think it should be

```
onRowSelection={(key) => this.onSelectRow(key) }
```

instead of

```
onRowSelection={this.onSelectRow}
```

You have to pass the key some how, I'm not sure where are you getting the key.

Then depending on your react style, you have to bind the `onSelectRow` some where, if you are using class then it should be in the constructor

```
class Component extends React.Components{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.onSelectRow = this.onSelectRow.bind(this);
    }
...
...
}
```

using arrow for function declaration in ES6 class is not a standard, it would work because of babel

you may want to provided full component code, so we can give further help

Comment: arrow function's just not working..I am not sure why? whenever I am introducing a arrow function, the checkbox for the `<Table>` is not working..though the functionality goes well..that's weird..Is there any other way of not using arrow function? I have to use setState, to set a variable's value.

Comment: thats all for the functionality..what is more needed? please let me know..I have no clue how to resolve this

Comment: for example, you said "arrow function's just not working.." how you are using arrow function. and "the checkbox is not working" what do you mean what is the expected behaviour and how is the checkbox component